# Installing Lighting Fixture - Ground Question

Tags: light-fixture

I have a lighting fixture that has the black, white and copper wire. The supply line has the same colors. I connected each color together. However, I realize that there is this green screw with my light fixture. Am i supposed to do something with that?

Comment: A picture would help. is that the only green screw? What are the colors of the other screws?

Comment: Is the green screw on the fixture, or in the ceiling box?

Comment: you might have needed that if there were no ground lead, but it sounds like you don't need it with your setup. To be 100%, I would make sure the lamp body has continuity with the ground (copper) lead, which it should. If not, then maybe the green screw attaches the ground to the lamp body somehow, in which case you should track down some directions to make sure it's being used correctly.

Comment: The standard colours for terminals are green=ground (and brass=black wire=hot, steel=white wire=neutral). http://www.hometime.com/Howto/projects/electric/elec_7.htm